# Установить демо схему Oracle

Tags: oracle

Читаю книгу: "*Oracle* для профессионалов" - Томас Кайт Кун Дарл. В книге написано, что нужно создать пользователя eoda с паролем foo. Это я сделал. Далее пишется, что нужно установить демо схему:

> введите команду `cd $0RACLE_HOME/sqlplus/demo;`
>
> после подключения от имени любого пользователя запустите сценарий `demoЬld.sql`

Установил переменную `ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1`

При выполнении данной команды пишет следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно установить? И как запускать сценарии?

Comment: вероятно они имели ввиду, что cd надо выполнить до запуска sql*plus, что бы потом было проще найти файл

Comment: И к тому же все примеры в книге будут под UNIX. Но это даже хорошо, вы же хотите профессионалом стать, заодно и это подучите.